# How do you open a folder in OSX using the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

On Windows, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you highlight on a folder in Windows Explorer will open that folder.

Same on Linux.

On OSX, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you highlight a folder edits the folder's name (like <kbd>F2</kbd> on Windows and Linux).

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing as on Windows, so that you'll open the folder? It doesn't have to be <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I'd like to know if there's another hotkey that does it.

The reason why I ask is because I like to navigate through deep folder structures by using the arrow keys for navigation and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to drill down into them.

Comment: It's a very stupid design to rename a folder when you press "enter"! Moreover, most of the time (for me almost always) when you select a folder you want to enter the folder, not renaming it. I hope Apple changes it in the future.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to open a folder.

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> will take you to the parent folder.
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> or just <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> will expand (toggle the triangle chic) the folder.
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or just <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> will retract the folder.

Also good to know is <kbd>Command</kbd> + any of <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> will toggle between the different view types (icon, list, columns, cover flow respectively).

Comment: Apple+O also opens the highlighted folder.

Comment: Correct, but he mentioned using the arrow keys extensively, so I went with the arrow keys.

Comment: FYI: on my MacBook Pro (MacOX X 10.7.3 Mountain Lion), when in list view, RightArrow and LeftArrow expands/retracts a folder, same as Command+RightArrow/Command+LeftArrow